# DC/OS installation

Tags: server

I'm new to DC/OS , I have setup 1 master with 3 agent for it. When I'm trying to `bash dcos_install.sh master` on the master node. I get the following errors:

```
    Starting DC/OS Install Process
Running preflight checks
Checking if DC/OS is already installed: PASS (Not installed)
dcos_install.sh: line 252: getenforce: command not found
PASS Is SELinux disabled?
Checking if docker is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking docker version requirement (>= 1.6): PASS (1.12.1)
Checking if curl is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if bash is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if ping is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if tar is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if xz is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if unzip is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if ipset is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if systemd-notify is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if systemd is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking systemd version requirement (>= 200): PASS (229)
Checking if group 'nogroup' exists: PASS 
Checking if port 53 (required by spartan) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 80 (required by adminrouter) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 443 (required by adminrouter) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 1050 (required by 3dt) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 2181 (required by zookeeper) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 5050 (required by mesos-master) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 7070 (required by cosmos) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8080 (required by marathon) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8101 (required by dcos-oauth) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8123 (required by mesos-dns) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8181 (required by exhibitor) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 9000 (required by metronome) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 9942 (required by metronome) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 9990 (required by cosmos) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 15055 (required by dcos-history) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 33107 (required by navstar) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 36771 (required by marathon) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 41281 (required by zookeeper) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 42819 (required by spartan) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 43911 (required by minuteman) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 46839 (required by metronome) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 61053 (required by mesos-dns) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 61420 (required by epmd) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 61421 (required by minuteman) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 62053 (required by spartan) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 62080 (required by navstar) is in use: PASS 
Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: WARNING: No swap limit support
PASS (aufs)
Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
Creating role file for master
Configuring DC/OS
Setting and starting DC/OS
A dependency job for dcos-setup.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
root@master:/tmp/dcos# journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

When I opened journalctl -xe below is shown.

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dcos-download.service has begun starting up.
Sep 27 09:52:11 master curl[3385]: * Couldn't open file /opt/dcos_install_tmp/bootstrap/5b4aa43610c57ee1d60b4aa0751a1fb75824c083.bootstrap.tar.xz
Sep 27 09:52:11 master curl[3385]: * Closing connection -1
Sep 27 09:52:11 master curl[3385]: curl: (37) Couldn't open file /opt/dcos_install_tmp/bootstrap/5b4aa43610c57ee1d60b4aa0751a1fb75824c083.bootstrap.tar.xz
Sep 27 09:52:11 master systemd[1]: dcos-download.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=37
Sep 27 09:52:11 master systemd[1]: Failed to start Pkgpanda: Download DC/OS to this host..
-- Subject: Unit dcos-download.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dcos-download.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 27 09:52:11 master systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Pkgpanda: Specialize DC/OS for this host..
-- Subject: Unit dcos-setup.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit dcos-setup.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Sep 27 09:52:11 master systemd[1]: dcos-setup.service: Job dcos-setup.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 27 09:52:11 master systemd[1]: dcos-download.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 27 09:52:11 master systemd[1]: dcos-download.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

is this a permission error or my configuration in my config files problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seem the problems lies in my configuration files. I solved the problem by changing the bootstrap_url inside my config.yaml and the problem is solved!

Comment: But what did you change it to?
What was the problem?
Thanks

Comment: This was 1 month + old question, but I will try my best to explain to you. Depending on the method you use to install DC/OS, CLI or Advanced. You change to line "bootstrap_url:" from your config.yaml to either "bootstrap_url: http://<yourbootstrapip>:<port>" you can use port 9000, or file:///opt/dcos_install_tmp/. and also make sure your master and agent node have the bootstrap's public key in their authorized_keys. Why are you asking? Are you facing similar problem? Please write out the details of the error and I see if I can help.

Comment: Updates: you can use bootstrap to fetch the dcos_install.sh from bootstrap, for advanced installer you can go to follow their online documents to curl the dcos_install.sh from bootstrap. 

I assume you use ubuntu as base. You can however use ubuntu for DC/OS but I advise you against it as it wasn't officially and fully supported/tested yet. So you might have problem install DC/OS in the way or even running it. You can follow the advanced installer guide to install DC/OS on ubuntu, do avoid cli method. It is advisable to use CentOS as base OS.